# What's the difference between casting the type of a 32 bit address to (BYTE *) and (DWORD *)

Tags: c++, windows, byte, portable-executable, dword

My program runs on a 32bit Windows ,so the type of the address in the virtual memory space is `DWORD`. And I want to hook  API by changing the address of the API in IAT . So , I get the base address of the image of the target process first.  Then , I try to get the start address of the IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER structure.

```
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32* pOptionalHeader=(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER*)((BYTE*)g_hCurrentProcessBase+pDosHeader->e_lfanew+24); //variable g_hCurrentProcessBase is the base address of the image of the target process
```

As you see , I  cast `g_hCurrentProcessBase` to `BYTE*` type, but at first , I casted it to `DWORD*` type , like this:

```
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32* pOptionalHeader=(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER*)((DWORD*)g_hCurrentProcessBase+pDosHeader->e_lfanew+24);
```

But it didn't work , getting a wrong address of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` structure.
But the the value of the variable `g_hCurrentProcessBase` should be a `DWORD` (I run it on 32bit Windows system) , but casting this variable to `DWORD *` didn't work , making it get a wrong address . But casting it to `BYTE*` works ,so what't the difference between them ?Why casting it to `DWORD *`  don't work?

Comment: *pointer arithmetic*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is different according to the type of the value it points to.

If you cast the pointer to `DWORD`, adding 24 actually adds `24*sizeof(DWORD)` to your address.

When casting to `BYTE`, it just adds 24 to the address (`BYTE` is 1 byte)

Note: If you *really* wanted your pointer as a `DWORD` (not the case here):

If you want to skip 24 bytes, just add `24/sizeof(DWORD)` to your `DWORD*` pointer.
Since DWORD is of size 4 it works as you want (even if it was 2 or 8 it would work).

Or compute the pointer using `BYTE*` cast, and *then* cast to `DWORD*`